# In genoPlotR how do I decrease the height between the dna_segs?

Tags: r

I'm trying to make a plot in genoPlotR and the default plot is spreading out the dna_segs by a large amount creating an awkward image. How do I decrease that space?
[Large white space inbetween dna_segs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/maI3I.png)

Below is my code:
`plot_gene_map(dna_segs=dna_segs, xlim=subseg)`

I looked through the manual and did not see any argument that did what I wanted. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't figured that one out. My workaround is to choose a size of my output device that makes the plot look the way I want it. For example:

```
require("png")
png("myplot.png", width = 10, height = 2.5, units="in", res=600)
plot_gene_map(...
dev.off()
```